# My perl CGI script gives "Internal Server Error"

Tags: perl, cgi

I'm new to writing CGI scripts and I'm having a problem with a script I've written whose purpose is to duplicate the string given in the first argument as much
times the value in the second argument. For example, for a call
http://localhost:8080/script.cgi? abc+3, the script should display "abcabcabc".

I'm in tmp/$USER/httpd/cgi-bin in Linux Red Hat.
When I start localhost I get the message "Internal Server Error"
Below is the code written in Perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# Get input from URL

my $input = $ENV{QUERY_STRING};

# Parse input into string and number of repetitions

my ($string, $reps) = $input =\~ /^(\\w+)+(\\d+)$/;

# Generate HTML output

print "Content-Type: text/html\\n\\n";
print "\<html\>\<body\>\\n";
print "<p>The string '$string' repeated $reps times:</p>\\n";
print "<p>" . ($string x $reps) . "</p>\\n";
print "\</body\>\</html\>\\n";`
```

I set chmod +x script.cgi and chmod +x to the cgi-bin directory but it didn't help.

Comment: This error can be caused by a variety of issues. 
1. Check the shebang line to make sure it's pointing to the correct location of Perl, you can use the command `which perl`.
2. Check the permissions of your file, make sure it has execute permissions.
3. You can check the Apache error logs (usually located in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` or `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`).

Comment: Include the web server you are running and operating system in your question. The answers/solution to your question will greatly depend on this knowledge.

Comment: When you get Internal Server Error, you need to check the log to get the error output by Perl.

Answer (score 3):

```perl
print "Content-Type: text/html\\n\\n";
```

prints

```perl
Content-Type: text/html\n\n
```

but you want to print `Content-Type: text/html` followed by two line feeds. This is achieved using

```perl
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Apache you may need to configure Apache to permit CGI and you will need to specify a ScriptAlias directive in your Apache configuration. [Instructions for that is here.](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html)

If you want to make 100% sure that the error is not related to your code but related to your web server configuration then create a script with the following contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
print "Hello World!"
```

If this script does not run then you know for sure it's a web server configuration issue. It may also be permission related. Your .cgi or .pl scripts will normally need the permission setting of 755.

In some situations Perl might not be installed. Make sure you have perl installed by running the following in the command prompt:

```
perl -v
```

If your perl version is not displayed then you know it is not installed and you will need to install it for your flavor of Linux.